# "System.in.read()" in Java

Tags: java, system.in

I have a problem with this method:

```
public void runTransaction(){
   //Some calculations...
   wait();
   //Other calculations...
}

private static void wait(){
   try {
        System.out.println("Press <enter> to continue");
        System.in.read();
    } 
    catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Input error...");
    }
}
```

but the programm does not continue after pressing Enter. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

**EDIT:** the programm does print the message "Press  to continue" but does not continue after that, it just waits for input.

Comment: Where is this method called? Give us a little bit more code

Comment: I edited my post. The methode `runTransaction` is called several times inside the `main` methode.

Answer (score 0):

Does your code even compile?  The `wait` method is public on the Object class, thus it can not be overridden as private.  Try using a different method name, say `waitForInput`.

Comment: Yes the code does compile, the message is printed and it waits for input

Comment: the wait method is static, thus does not over-ride the Object.wait instance method.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't even compile:

1. [`in.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) can throw an `IOException`, which you need to handle. (**EDIT:** Looks like you fixed this issue in your snippet.)
2. You can't name this method `wait()` since that hides `Object`'s [`wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29).

Once these errors are corrected, the code should work as expected.

Comment: @user3019653 The snippet still shouldn't compile since the method's called `wait()`.

Comment: It does compile, however i changed the name to `wait_enter`but got the same result

Comment: @user3019653 What Java version is this?

Comment: `java -version` gives me:
`java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)`

Answer (score 0):

Your code should run as expected if you have changed the name to wait_enter, you just need to make sure that you have clicked into the console before pressing enter so it registers the enter.

Comment: better add this as a comment rather than a answer.

Comment: As I just joined last week (notice the one rep point), I can't add comments to other peoples posts.